# how to clean docker images from azure devops build server

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, devops

I am using the azure devops pipeline to build a docker image for my asp.net web application. I have to use self-hosted agent as build and deployment server. After each time running the CI pipeline, new images are created and then pushed to Docker registry. now the problem is , the images which are built and saved on the agent! after a while the agent disk faces the low disk and I have to delete the old images manually.
How can I delete docker images after pushing to the registry during the CI pipeline?

please check attached snapshot.[image]

Answer (score 3):

After pushing image add command line step to delete image:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'docker rmi -f IMAGE:TAG'
```

or more destructive

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'docker system prune -a --force'
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but if I use above commands, I will miss the based images using for build. I have to only remove the new docker images which pushed to Registry.

Comment: I agree, but you can delete only one image by pass image name as a variable :)

Comment: or in prune you could add `--filter`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/#filtering
or even use `docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q --filter="YOUR_FILTER")`

Comment: would you please check attached snapshot? how can I remove the untagged image?

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
docker rmi -f image-name
```

which will forcefully remove the image after you push the image to the registry

Comment: would you please attached snapshot?

Comment: If you're talking about delete <none> named images, do 
docker rmi -f <image id> 
Try this

Answer (score 0):

After you push the image to the registry add a cmd task with the command to remove the image:

```
docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]
```

For example:

```
docker rmi test1:latest
```

Comment: Would you please check attached snapshot

Answer (score 0):

How about using `docker system prune`. Doing this usually removes all dangling images from the system but using it with `-a` should take care of removing any unused images as well.

Please refer to official [documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) .